# Write product of n variables as a sum of nth power monomials

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a commutative set of $n$-variables
$$
z_1 z_2z_3...z_n
$$
Is there a clever way to write them as sum of simple linear combinations, such as,
$$
z_1z_2z_3...z_n=a_1(\sum \lambda_{1j}z_j)^n+a_2(\sum \lambda_{2j}z_j)^n+...+a_M(\sum \lambda_{Mj}z_j)^n\ \ \ ?
$$
For example, when $n=2$ we can write
$$
z_1z_2=\frac 14(z_1+z_2)^2-\frac 14(z_1-z_2)^2
$$
but I am having a hard time generalizing this to even the case $n=3$ even though I know it is possible.  Any comments or insights appreciated.

Edit: I can now do it for $n$=3 but it involves 6 summands instead of the 3, and the method does not appear to generalize to higher order.  Ideally I would like to use the smallest number of terms possible since it has to hold for any $n$, including very large $n$.

Comment: For $n=3$ you can write
$$6xyz=(x+y+z)^3-(x+y)^3-(x+z)^3-(y+z)^3+x^3+y^3+z^3.$$

Comment: yes, I found something similar invovling phases like $(x+e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}y+e^{\frac{4\pi i}3}z)^3$ but unfortunately I cannot generalize it to n=4, and 5, etc.  Intuitively there should be a generating functional sort of like how Newton's polynomials generate the determinant in linear algebra.

Edit: actually yours might generalize more easily than my phase approach.

Comment: For $n=4$ you can write
$$24wxyz=(w+x+y+z)^4-(w+x+y)^4-(w+x+z)^4-(w+y+z)^4-(x+y+z)^4+(w+x)^4+(w+y)^4+(w+z)^4+(x+y)^4+(x+z)^4+(y+z)^4-w^4-x^4-y^4-z^4.$$

Comment: Thank you, I think I see the pattern now.   

Incidentally, for n=3 I was able to do it in 6 terms instead of 7.  Do you suppose there is a minimal solution with something like n(n+1)/2 terms (just a guess)?

Comment: Here's a solution with $2^n$ terms: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780700/the-symmetric-algebra-of-a-vector-space-is-generated-by-powers/2780716#2780716 (probably the exact pattern you are seeing). Good question about minimizing the number of terms, though. This amounts to asking for the "symmetric tensor rank" of certain symmetric $n$-tensors; this has been studied in https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.1681v2 for example.